# Javascript replace method with both array and regex

Tags: javascript, regex

How i can replace any character except 0-9 a-z and and array of some characters with '' (nothing).

My code is look like this

```
Var pCharArray = ['l', 'o', 'c'];//local characters
Var stringOrginal = 'Some Text';
stringOrginal.replace(/(^[0-9][a-z]pCharArray)/g, '');
```

Every character that is not 0-9 **AND** not a-z **AND** not in pCharArray, should be removed.

Comment: Note that the array is useless here as all it's elements are inside `a-z`. [This demo change the example a bit to show it works](http://jsfiddle.net/YEza7/1/).

Comment: Is the `pCharArray` every going to have non `a-z` characters? ...like @gdoron said...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

^ character means negation only when used inside of character class, i.e. [^a] means any character except a. When it's used outside of the character class it means the beginning of the string.

Correct code:

```
stringOrginal.replace(new RegExp("[^0-9a-z"+pCharArray.join('')+"]", 'g'), '');
```

Also please note if you want to include backslash or closing bracket to the pCharArray array you should state them as '\\' and '\]' there respectively.

Comment: Nice, but if OP adds some metachars inside the array (such as `-`) it may require escaping depending on its position. +1

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Actually only \ and ] should be escaped, all other characters will be treated as control once only at first position.

Comment: @bjornd. What about `\ / [ ] -` chars?

Comment: @gdoron As I noted only \ and ] are problematic and should be escaped.

Comment: I always have trouble understanding what really requires escaping inside character classes, but still, how come `-` doesn't need escaping (of course, if it's at beginning or end of the character class it won't require escaping), but if I have `"[0"+"-"+"9]"`, wouldn't it create a `[0-9]` interval?

Answer (score 4):

You can use this:

```
stringOrginal.replace(new RegExp("[^0-9a-z" + pCharArray.join('')+"]", 'g'), "");
```

Note:

```
Var => var (lowercase)
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/YEza7/)

Comment: This will do the opposite: 0-9 and a-z and any character in pCharArray will be removed.

Comment: Why downvote answers with typos instead of just commenting the issue? Will never know, I suppose. Upvoted.

Comment: Thanks you, your answer is true, but in first edit that i tested your code and @bjornd code ,bjornd code works for me.